# How to disable tab discarding in chrome using JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I'd like to disable chrome discarding tab for my page in chrome://discards/ using Javascript so it persist after closing the page or chrome. I know I could do that with extension, but I'd like to build my own solution either inside the app or with new extension, where do I start? How can I even reach chrome://discards using JS?

Comment: When I try `window.open("chrome://discards/");` I get "not allowed to open local resource", meaning you can't do this without an extension

Comment: @ChrisG how do I do that with an extension, any ideas? I'd love if you would also recommend me some articles/videos on how to do the extension, never done that before

Comment: I don't know, please do your own research. Maybe your website can do something in the background from time to time to prevent being discarded?

Answer (score 3):

According [Google support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12929150?visit_id=638125928653270434-2611685942&p=chrome_memory_saver&rd=1#memory_saver&zippy=%2Cturn-memory-saver-on-or-off%2Ckeep-specific-sites-active) the following can prevent the site from being discarded:

- Active audio or video (playback or calls)
- Screen share
- Page notifications
- Active downloads
- Partially filled forms
- Connected devices (USB or Bluetooth)

It seems that the easiest way to keep your tab working is to play some inaudible audio at some regular intervals from the web page.