# Prevent Google Chrome unloading or discarding tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome frequently discards (i.e. 'unloads') tabs that haven't been active for a while. That makes sense if low on RAM, but I have ~70GB spare RAM.

I put this into the address bar: `chrome://discards` and can see all open tabs and their discard status (AKA 'Loading State') i.e. `loaded` vs `unloaded`).

How can I configure chrome to never discard tabs?

#### What I know so far

I can see someone's asked how to do it using javascript ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73107224/5783745)).

I tried searching Chrome settings but no results:

[image]

I also tried searching the flags (`chrome://flags/`) for anything related to 'tabs', 'unloading', 'discarding' etc, but couldn't spot anything there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to chrome settings by copy/pasting this into the address bar:

```
chrome://settings/?search=memory+saver
```

Search for 'memory saver'

The turn it off:

[image]

#### Notes

- You can check that it's working by periodically going here: `chrome://discards/` and making sure none of the tabs discarded/uploaded
- All credit to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1774148/928461) answer.

Comment: Thank you! I have this one site that is really slow, so I open tabs so I don't have to wait for them to load. I added that under "Always keep these sites active" and hopefully I will have less waiting to do now!